# Sending NFC signal from My RPI

Tags: nfc

I wanted to record data on my RPI.
Then I want to send this data with NFC to a Android Mobile app.
Is this possible, and if yes, which component would I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PN532 or MFRC522. The Elechouse PN532 is cheap on eBay. Doesn't have stellar range active-to-passive, i.e. when reading or writing tokens, but may have much better speed and range with a mobile phone. Pay attention to voltage, 3V3 for SPI and 5V for I2C.

Use libnfc, plenty of samples on Google.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/libnfc

Note that the Adafruit shield or breakout board (with its hefty pricetag) is only slightly better in terms of range, 1-2 cm.